# PHP Email - Variables Not Being Detected?

Tags: php, html, email, variables

Ok - I've recently purchased a template and have an OK understanding of PHP.

The problem i'm getting is the PHP Variables are not being detected (or are blank) even though i've clearly declared them, I have lost my wits with this issue.

In transferConfirm.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$clink = $_POST['clink'];
$mviews = $_POST['mviews'];
$subs = $_POST['subs'];
$cnetwork = $_POST['cnetwork'];
$nnetwork = $_POST['nnetwork'];
```

In transfer.php

```
            <section id="contact-form">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-12 section-title-price wow flipInX">
                    <h2><small>Partner Transfer</small></h2>
                    <p class="lead"><span class="highlight">Learn More About Network Transfers</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center wow flipInX" id="contact">
                    <div id="message"></div>
                    <form method="post" action="transferConfirm.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                    <fieldset>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                    <p><strong>Channel Information</strong></p>
                        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" placeholder="Full Name"/>
                        <br />
                        <input name="cid" type="text" id="cid" placeholder="Customer ID"/>
                        <br />
                        <input name="clink" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Channel Link"/>
                        <br /> 
                        <input name="mviews" type="text" id="mviews" placeholder="Monthly Views"/>
                        <br />
                        <input name="subs" type="text" id="subs" placeholder="Subscribers"/>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                    <p><strong>Network Information</strong></p>
                        <input name="cnetwork" type="text" id="cnetwork" placeholder="Current Network Name"/>
                        <br />
                        <input name="nnetwork" type="text" id="nnetwork" placeholder="New Network Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Transfer" />
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I know some of the code may look dodgey in the HTML - But i can't see it being the reason of the error. However, the $name variable seems to be the only one working?!

Here's where the error occurs:

```
    echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h4 class='highlight'>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your messaged has been submitted to us.</h4>";
echo "<h4 class='highlight'>Thank you <strong>$cid</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</h4>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";
```

The $name seems to be working but the $cid isn't?!

Comment: So print your POST-array with vardump and find out what's in it. If cid isn't in it, there's something wrong with your form. If it's there there's something wrong between the place where you grab the variable and where you put it in the text. What did you try so far to debug? What did you find?

Comment: The VARS are empty and the form seems just fine as you can see above. I think it's the CSS or JS, but i have no idea. It works on another server which doesn't include the CSS or Javascript files

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitting to **transferConfirm.php**, not **confirmTransfer.php**.  Try changing either the filename or the form submit action.

Comment: Sorry, by fault of my own that was the original file name and i miss-typed it into the post! :c